# JavaScript sorting on date (but not the "usual" way)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I'm trying to sort a JS array, but in a different fashion. Here's my scenario:

Say we have the following dates in the array (these will be each `item`'s `expiryDate`)

```
1. 2015/09/23
2. 2015/10/10
3. 2015/07/05
4. 2015/07/24
```

And the current date is `2015/07/04`
And we select `2015/09` (which is `vm.sortModel` in the example) as the sorting date
The display order must be as follows -

```
3. 
1. 
4. 
2.
```

Here's what I have so far, but it's obviously not working...

```
for (var i = 0; i < vm.tableData.length; i++) {
    var entity = vm.tableData[i];
    entity.items.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (a.expiresThisWeek() < b.expiresThisWeek()) {
            return 1;
        }

        //Now check for stuff in months AFTER the selected year/month combo
        if (vm.sortModel) {
            var tmp = vm.sortModel.split('/');
            var currentDateSelection = new Date(tmp[0], tmp[1]);

            if (a.getExpiryDateObject() >= currentDateSelection) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        if (a.getExpiryDateObject() < b.getExpiryDateObject()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (a.getExpiryDateObject() > b.getExpiryDateObject()) {
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    });
}
```

Basically, if an item expires in this week, it must be at the top of the table, then we should list all the items in the "selected month", then all the months AFTER that month, and *then* only the months before that.

Very strange, I know, but business gets what business wants.

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**

Here's the `expiresThisWeek` method

```
model.expiresThisWeek = function() {
    var todayDate = new Date();
    //We want to check if the item expires within 7 days from today
    var endDate = new Date(todayDate.getFullYear(), todayDate.getMonth(), todayDate.getDate() + 7);
    var date = model.getExpiryDateObject();

    return todayDate < date && date < endDate;
}
```

Comment: so the date is not a date object, but just a string?  then I'd turn it into a timestamp first.

Comment: @lxer no, it's a proper date object. Hence `a.getExpiryDateObject()` and `var currentDateSelection = new Date(tmp[0], tmp[1]);`

Comment: what does `expiresThisWeek()` return?

Comment: @yarons just a boolean, it's a simple comparison function. Will post it as part of the question...